# Does the Nyx 2 ability work on bosses?

Tags: warframe

Nyx's second ability, Psychic Bolts, applies a potent armor and shield strip ability. The wiki doesn't say one way or the other, but I was hoping to find out: does this armor/shield strip work on bosses as well?

Answer (score 2):

I tried on some bosses.

- Vor
- Tyl Regor
- Lieutenant
- Lech Kril
- Stalker

None of them seemed to be influenced in any way. (250% Ability Strength)